# Why is TypeScript returning a discriminated union with optional keys that will never be possible?

Tags: typescript

I am hoping to return a discriminated union but it is combining the keys in the object. I realise that I could explicitly define the return type but I was hoping that I wouldn't have to. I have tried a few different options that I will put in the solutions.

```
export const testFn = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) 
    return { valid: true, data: { your: 1 } } as const;

  return { valid: false, error: { my: "error" } } as const;
};

type T1 = ReturnType<typeof testFn>
// gives
// type T1 = {
//     valid: true;
//     data: {
//         your: 1;
//     };
//     error?: undefined;
// } | {
//     valid: false;
//     error: {
//         my: 'error';
//     };
//     data?: undefined;
// }

// why doesn't it/how do I get it to return 
// type T1 = {
//     valid: true;
//     data: {
//         your: 1;
//     };
// } | {
//     valid: false;
//     error: {
//         my: 'error';
//     };
// }
```

The main thing that I have realised is that it is combining (i.e. not discriminating) due to the similarities of the returned objects.

Just as an example that does work that leads me to think that it should be possible. The following returns a discriminated union as I would have hoped:

```
export const testFn = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) 
    return { valid: true, data: { your: 1 } } as const;

  return [{ valid: false, error: { my: "error" } }] as const;
};

type T1 = ReturnType<typeof testFn>
// gives
// {
//     readonly valid: true;
//     readonly data: {
//         readonly your: 1;
//     };
// } | readonly [{
//     readonly valid: false;
//     readonly error: {
//         readonly my: "error";
//     };
// }]
```

Comment: It _is_ inferring a union return type, which you could discriminate on the `valid` property.

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed; your `T1` is indeed a discriminated union type, as evidenced [here](https://tsplay.dev/NdvRkW). What should we do here? If all you want is a discriminated union then the issue isn't reproducible and we should close the question as such.  If you just don't like the particular discriminated union that comes out, you should [edit] the question to ask about that instead, and explain exactly what goes wrong with the current union, since right now there's no motivating use case.

Comment: Apologies @jcalz and jonrsharpe, I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: "It is combining (i.e. not discriminating) due to the similarities of the returned objects." This still isn't true, it *is* discriminating; when `valid` is `true`, then `data` will exist and that `error` will be missing-or-`undefined`, but when `valid` is `false`, then `error` will exist, and `data` will be missing-or-`undefined`. That's exactly correct and useful, and you still haven't demonstrated what actually goes wrong if you let it stay like this. Could you provide a [mre], with code, where something bad happens? Just saying you expected something else isn't sufficient.

Answer (score -2):

This answer is incredibly unclear and I'm hoping for a considerably clearer option as it only gets less clear with less minimal examples.

```
export const testFn = () => {
  const isMoreThanHalf = Math.random() > 0.5;

  const rtnMap = {
    a: isMoreThanHalf
      ? ({ valid: true, data: { your: 1 } } as const)
      : undefined,
    b: isMoreThanHalf
      ? undefined
      : ({ valid: false, error: { my: "error" } } as const),
  } as const;

  const rtn = isMoreThanHalf ? rtnMap.a : rtnMap.b;
  const rtn2 = rtn as Exclude<typeof rtn, undefined>;

  return rtn2;
};

type T1 = ReturnType<typeof testFn>;
// gives
// {
//     valid: true;
//     data: {
//         your: 1;
//     };
// } | {
//     valid: boolean;
//     error: {
//         my: 'error';
//     };
// }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).